# How to do pagination across multiple tabs using Kaminari Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I have a method which fetches results using solr. for eg.

```
 def test
    @result1 = Model1.search do
       fulltext params[:search]
       paginate page: params[:page], per_page: 12
     end
    @result2 = Model2.search do
       fulltext params[:search]
       paginate page: params[:page], per_page: 12
     end

 end
```

Now I have 2 results and I am displaying this in test page across 2  tabs.

When I display content via tabs, the data gets populated correctly in each tab, but I have a problem in pagination.

When I click suppose say on page number 3 in result2 tab it displays page3 of result2 but when I click on result1 tab it takes me to page3 of result1 tab. Where as it should go to page1 when I click on the result1 tab.

```
 <%= paginate @result1 ,:params => { :anchor => 'result1' }%>

 <%= paginate @result2 ,:params => { :anchor => 'result2' }%>
```

How can I solve this. I am using kaminari gem for pagination.

Comment: you can use the params hash and pass unique identifier such params=>{:from_tab1=>"tab1",:from_tab1=>"tab2"}.So in the controller,you can use it to identify its coming from which tab and then paginate and update it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option `param_name` in kaminari like so

```
<%= paginate @result1, param_name: 'result1' %>
```

and likewise for @result2. Then instead of `params[:anchor]` you should use `params[:result1]` to get the page number. Since you'll be using different param names for @result1 and @result2, they won't interfere with each other